# the exception won't hit the method declaration?

Tags: java

When using the Eclispe, I found when setting the breakpoint on the method declaration, the breakpoint will never be hit. Is this true?

Breakpoint  public void handleRequest(final Buffer buffer) {
  blah blah blah
}

Comment: Could you try to edit the question for clarity? Formatting and/or screenshots could be useful.

Comment: It seems to work fine for me. It seems to pause at where the method is called.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Helios. Despite you can set the breakpoint on the method declaration (it's called method entry breakpoint), the debugger always stop at the first line in the method body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it wont break on the line of method declaration. it will stop if you are putting break point on first line of the method.

Comment: This is because the breakpoint occurs instantly before the line. Since the method begins at the line, you are simply breakpointing the whitespace in between methods.